# line plot by month and year using FacetGrid

Tags: pandas, dataframe, seaborn, facet-grid, line-plot

I have this dataset:

| year | month | victims |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2016 | 7 | 4869 |
| 2016 | 8 | 4817 |
| 2016 | 9 | 4900 |
| 2016 | 10 | 4873 |
| 2016 | 11 | 4461 |
| 2016 | 12 | 4908 |
| 2017 | 1 | 4717 |
| 2017 | 2 | 4489 |
| 2017 | 3 | 4733 |
| 2017 | 4 | 4549 |
| 2017 | 5 | 4928 |
| 2017 | 6 | 4767 |
| 2017 | 7 | 4713 |
| 2017 | 8 | 4992 |
| 2017 | 9 | 4885 |
| 2017 | 10 | 5049 |
| 2017 | 11 | 4861 |
| 2017 | 12 | 4667 |

....

I want to plot the number of victims by year and month

I used this code :

```
sb.lineplot(data=number_victims,  x='month', y='victims', hue='year')
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), title = 'month', title_fontsize = 12)
```

this is the result:

[image]

I tried to use FacetGrid to get a better view of each year

this is my code :

```
g = sb.FacetGrid(number_victims, col="year", margin_titles=True, col_wrap=3, height=3, aspect=2)
g.map_dataframe(
    sb.lineplot, x="month", y="victims"
)
g.fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.8)
g.fig.suptitle('The overall trend of victims number by month and year');
```

and this is the result :

[image]

So I have 2 questions:

1. How to sort the months in the first graph? (to start from 1 to 12)
2. Why in the second graph the name of months are from 1 to 10 ? and in 2016 it suppose to start from month #7 not #1, how can I fix that?

Thank you so much.

Comment: You need to update matplotlib and seaborn to 3.4.3 and 0.11.2 respectively. `sns.lineplot(data=df,  x='month', y='victims', hue='year')` works without issue and it should be `sns.relplot(kind='line', data=df, col='year', x="month", y="victims", col_wrap=3)`. Don't use `FacetGrid` directly. [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnaDf.png). Check [`df.info()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2r5Pl.png) and the 3 columns should be int type.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Thanks that works.